# Get value from jsp via spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've created MVC Template via `Spring Tool Suite IDE`, but I can't realize, how to get values from `jsp`. For exmaple - I've created text input in `jsp`

```
<input type="text" />
```

but how to get the value to controller to be able to work with it there? I know, that when I add atribute to model in my controller, then I can access it via `${name}` , but how to do it the other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a form and then submit the value to the controller ...

Something like :

```
<form name="foo" action="/foo/bar" method="post">
    <input name="fieldName" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>
```

And then get it in your controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar")
    public String testAction(@RequestParam String fieldName) {
        // yourValue contain the value post from the html form
        return "yourview";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so..I was used to mark the input with <id="${something}"/> tag from jsp. And how to retrieve the value in the controller?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean... To retrieve the value in the controller you can use the @RequestParam annotation like I did in the example.

Comment: sorry..I was writting faster, than thinking ;) thx a lot ! :)